# Newly created WebForm in folder is not found error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

I'm making a project in ASP.NET MVC, the idea is make independent views, for that purpose i have created a public folder and inside of it I have created a `WebForm.aspx` with its own codebehind `.aspx.cs`. I have installed Bootstrap from NuGet packager, have referenced the scripts into the WebForm like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <link href="../../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="../../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/popper.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
                <p>This is some text.</p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

but when I run it it shows me an error:

[image]

this is the structure:

[image]

but when I run it from a webform made out of a folder it runs properly.

[image]

How can make the aspx located inside public folder work?

Comment: You need to configure a Public controller to route to your view(s).

Comment: How that supose to be? @NathanChampion

Comment: @Volazh could you show the code of your PublicView.aspx page?

Comment: @Siavas I have posted the public aspx code at the beginin of the post!

Comment: My bad @Volazh!

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP 404 page indicates that the `PublicView` controller action method name does not exist on the controller definition. If you want to associate webforms page with MVC routing path style e.g. `/Public/PublicView` mapped to `/Views/Public/PublicView.aspx` without creating controller action to that page, the [`MapPageRoute()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.routing.routecollection.mappageroute?view=netframework-4.7.2) method may suits your need.

Just make sure to put webforms route paths before default MVC route, because `RouteConfig` evaluates route definition from top to bottom, hence most specific routes evaluated first:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // webforms page route
    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "PublicView",
        "Public/PublicView",
        "~/Views/Public/PublicView.aspx"
    );

    // MVC route
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

If you want to map all ASPX pages inside a folder with one `MapPageRoute`, adjust it to contain page name placeholder:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // webforms page route
    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "PublicView",
        "Public/{pageName}",
        "~/Views/Public/{pageName}.aspx"
    );

    // MVC route
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**Notes:**

1) If you want to use ASPX page as MVC view page which rendered from controller action method, it is necessary to change `Inherits` with `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage` in `Page` directive like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" ... %>
```

Then replace webforms server controls with MVC HTML helpers before calling the page from controller as provided below:

```
public class PublicController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult PublicView()
    {
        return View("PublicView");
    }
}
```

2) Avoid replacing `System.Web.UI.Page` to `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage` namespace for ASPX pages in code-behind directly, because it may trigger several issues while using server controls.

**Reference:** [How to define routes for Web Forms applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/cc668177(v=vs.140))

Answer (score 0):

You only need to tell the server more information about your page, including its location. This can be done with the `<%@ Page >` tag, which has to be inserted at the start of your page, as follows:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PublicView.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Public.PublicView" %>
```

If the page you create is a master page (which seems to be as you have your `<head>` tag in there, you would have to use `Master` instead and select appropriate file type when creating the new page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PublicView.master.cs" Inherits="PublicView.SiteMaster" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. It's working. Hope to help, my friend :))

1) Config Routing info:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            // This informs MVC Routing Engine to send any requests for .aspx page to the WebForms engine
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

2) Call the action in the controller:

```
public class PublishController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Publish
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("WebForm1");
        }        
    }
```

3) In a code behind webform:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                //Your code here
            }
        }
    }
```